# Undelegate Method

Tags: java, eclipse, delegates, refactoring, migration

I'm trying to do a conversion from one 3rd party library to another (`gwt-ext` to `gxt`).  To help minimize upfront changes, and to ensure consistency and testability, we decided to create proxy classes that implement the old API and map them to the new API.

For example, something like `Panel` might now be a `ContentPanel`.  The old Panel may have had a method called `setEl(String name)` that should now map to `setElement(String name)`.  To facilitate this, we created a `Panel` class that contains a `ContentPanel`.  Then in Eclipse, we called `Source -> Generate Delegate Methods...` to create the methods that both APIs might have in common.  Then any missing or changed APIs we create by had in our `Panel` class and pass along to the appropriate handler in our contained `ContentPanel`.  When we're done with this, we want to refactor out our class (basically Inlining) and have everything call the methods on 'ContentPanel' directly and use any magic we did in out hand implemented methods in every spot that the old method was called.

What is the best way to do this?  I thought there was already a refactoring in Eclipse that could handle this, but I'm not finding it.

Of course if you think there is a better way to do a migration like this, I'm open to suggestions on that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: don't.  Using the target object as a component and then delegating was the wrong strategy.  We were better off making our proxy extend our target API, then implementing whatever methods where missing in the new API and mapping them to the new API.  Then inlining worked as needed.

Comment: We went ahead with this solution and looking back, I think this is the correct way to go.  Personally I think it saved us a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has [inlining refactoring](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/refactoring.html#Inline_Method) which could be quite useful in your situation. Not sure Eclipse has one but maybe there is a plugin that does inlining?

Comment: Eclipse does have inlining, but it didn't work the way we needed it.  I think the strategy was flawed.